# Difference between elementary submodel and elementary substructure

Tags: logic, terminology, model-theory

This is a really "elementary" question, forgive the pun.

What is the difference between an **elementary submodel** and an **elementary substructure** (in first-order Logic)?

Sincere thanks for help.

Comment: Model is a structure which satisfies a particular theory. Without the context of a theory this is just a substructure. When adding the context of a theory this is the same thing because both structure satisfy the same sentences [read: axioms].

Comment: None. Both terms denote the same objects. It is simply that sometimes we talk of models and sometimes we talk of structures. Typically, "model" is reserved for "model of a theory $T$". If no theory is being discussed, "elementary submodel of $\mathcal M$" means "elementary substructure that is a model of the theory of $\mathcal M$", but of course, any elementary substructure of $\mathcal M$ is a model of this theory. So the two uses are equivalent. It is more a matter of personal taste than anything else.

Comment: @Asaf: What if the sentences are not all equations (universal sentences)? E.g. I can imagine that a subring of a field is a substructure (in the language of rings), but the submodels are only the subfields... $\quad$ well.. if they are *elemantary*, then of course, this differentiation doesn't play..

Comment: Same thing. In set theory submodel seems to be more common than elsewhere.

Comment: @Berci: I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let M be a structure and T a theory that it models.
A substructure N of M need not model T.
if N models T, then we say that N is a submodel of M relative to T.
Otherwise, if N is a substructure of M that is not a submodel relative to T.
Thus the only distinction comes when a theory lurks in the background.

As an example, consider the signature S = (+, 0) where 0 is a unary relation symbol. then the naturals (N, +, 0) is an S-structure. Let A = {1, 2, 3, ...}. By restricting + to AxAxA and 0 to A, then A is naturally an S-structure. Since the inclusion map of A into N is an embedding (i.e. preserves atomics and negations of atomics over A), we get that A is a substructure of N. But relative to the full theory T of N, A is not a submodel of N since N models "exists x 0x" whereas M does not model "exists x 0x" as {0} intersect A = emptyset.

So there is indeed a difference between submodel and substructure, but it depends on the context.